# How do I make VBA wait for IE page to load?

Tags: excel, vba

I am automating IE through VBA and I can't seem to get the VBA code to wait until the page is loaded before grabbing the document.  This is leading to all sorts of failures with my code being too fast. How can I get VBA to wait for the IE page to load?  Many of the methods I have tried I have found on stackoverflow but none seem to work for me.

`ie` is my `InternetExplorer` object.

I have tried, to no avail:

```
Do
    If ie.readyState = 4 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop
```

Also:

```
Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Also:

```
Do 
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

I even tried:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

...

Do
    Sleep 250
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

None of these have worked, the code skips over the loop immediately and tries to grab the html document of the page even though the page has not finished loading.

I am navigating to a login page, filling in a username and password, and clicking log-in.  After I log-in I need to change some fields (drop downs and text boxes).  After I change these fields I use VBA to click a button to save the settings and then navigate to another page.  The code does not properly set the fields because it skips past waiting for the page to load, thus I enter the next part of my code with incorrect settings.

I am wondering if this is possibly due to an ajax request?  I don't know how to even tell.

Does anyone have a reliable means of waiting for a page to load in IE before grabbing the html document?

I know the code is doing what I want because if I manually step through it and wait for the page to load, it behaves as expected.

I can add more clarification if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the DocumentCompleted event to fire?

Comment: I haven't.  I'm not that familiar with using an object's events in that manner in VBA.  I am googling and not turning up great documentation.

Comment: Ok, I have provided an example in my answer. By the way, it is DocumentComplete without d at the end. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could wait for the [DocumentComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event to fire. But for that you need to have the browser control placed on a worksheet. In the code of that worksheet, enter this code (assuming you named the browser control `ie`):

```
Private docComplete As Boolean

Private Sub ie_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, url As Variant)
    docComplete = True
End Sub

Public Sub NavigateAndWait(url As String)
    docComplete = False
    ie.Navigate url
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until docComplete
End Sub

Sub Main()
    ' Example use
    NavigateAndWait "www.google.com"
    MsgBox "Ready"
End Sub
```

By making `NavigateAndWait` a `Public Sub` you can call it from other modules you might have. It is best to move code that needs `ie` into this sheet's module. Note that the browser control must be visible and on the active sheet for the DocumentComplete event to fire.

Comment: Thanks for this example.  It seems to not like that `ie` is not declared in the `NavigateAndWait` subroutine as it gives me a variable not defined error.  Does that sound right to you?  Do I need to pass my `ie` object in to that subroutine?

Comment: Well, in your question you said you had called your browser object `ie`, and you provided code using `ie`... so I used `ie`. Make sure to put this code in the module of the sheet that has the `ie` browser object

Comment: Yeah my object `ie` must have too narrow of a scope, I will try and change that.

Comment: Well, you must put the ie_DocumentComplete in the sheet's code, ... the sheet that has the browser object on it. Don't try otherwise. In fact, if you double click the browser object you get in the sheet module where you can select the DocumentComplete event from the dropdown. It will generate an empty body for it.

Comment: It's all in one code module (not in sheet code).  Would that be the issue?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, follow these steps: go to the Excel sheet that has the object. Double click it. You end up in the code window, with a Private Sub created for you, but which you don't need. Select from the drop down at the right the Document Complete . That routine must reside there. You cannot move it to a generic module.

Comment: Ah I think I know the issue (and why I was confused).  I don't actually have the web browser object in Excel, I am just creating an instance of IE in my code module.  Hmm.

Comment: In that case you have no possibility to trap the DocumentComplete event. Maybe reconsider putting the object on a sheet? I thought first you could hide that sheet, but the DocumentComplete event only fires if the browser control is visible.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry I don't have enough rep so I have to add an answer but did you try 1000 or 2000 (1 or 2 seconds) in your 3rd option? Depending on what IE is doing it may take more than 250 milliseconds to load.

Comment: Well it shouldn't matter as it should stay in the loop until the ReadyState is 4 right?  So it sleeps for 250 ms, then checks again to see if page is ready, if not, sleeps again 250 ms and so on.  At least that's how I intended it to work.