# Catch event trigger from external application in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I use VBA to automate an external application that recently changed their COM API. The new API loads files asynchronously (used to be synchronous) so I need to wait for the file loaded trigger before I continue when I try to load a file.

I have tried the methods listed on the Microsoft website ([EX1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/electronic-business-cards/using-events-with-automation), [EX2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler)) which were also part of an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353565/how-do-i-make-vba-wait-for-ie-page-to-load) on StackOverflow.

Below is the code I have in a class module named UCExternal to contain the external application object:

```
Public WithEvents obj As External.Application
Private fileLoaded As Boolean

Private Sub obj_OnFileLoaded(ByVal lLayer As Long, ByVal strUNCPath As String)
    Debug.Print lLayer
    Debug.Print strUNCPath
    fileLoaded = True
End Sub

Public Sub LoadSingleFile(fileStr As String)
    fileLoaded = False
    
    obj.LoadFile 0, fileStr
    
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until fileLoaded
    
End Sub
```

And then this is what I had in a normal code module to run using a button on the sheet:

```
Sub TryLoadFile()

    Dim extObj as New UCExternal

    set extObj.obj = CreateObject("External.Application")
    filePath = "path/to/file"
    extObj.LoadSingleFile filePath

End Sub
```

The event code never seems to fire and instead the Do Loop just runs until Excel crashes. I don't know if there is a way to confirm the application actually sent the event trigger? I have read through the new documentation for the application and that is the event they say to wait for. I have reached out to them for help as well but I wasn't sure if there was something more general I may have been missing. I have not worked with events external to Excel in the past. If I just step through it using the debugger and manually exit the Do Loop eventually the rest of the code that works on the loaded file works as well, so it does load the file.

Answer (score 0):

`extObj` needs to be declared outside of `TryLoadFile`, or it will go out of scope and get cleared as soon as `TryLoadFile` completes

```vb
Dim extObj as New UCExternal

Sub TryLoadFile()
    Set extObj = New UCExternal
    set extObj.obj = CreateObject("External.Application")
    filePath = "path/to/file"
    extObj.LoadSingleFile filePath
End Sub
```

Comment: Even so, it should fire the event before it goes out of scope. I have a stop put in if it ever enters the event firing sub but it never does. The scope shouldn't change that. I tried just in case but nothing has changed.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't looked too closely at your class implementation.  That's kind of going against the grain of asynchronous programming - typically you would use a callback to run the step after the load is complete, but that's trickier in VBA than in some other languages.  Try ditching the loop with do events and just put a Debug.Print or MsgBox in the `obj_OnFileLoaded` handler and see if it fires.